# C# TPL Dataflowライブラリとは何かについて知りたい。

Tags: c#

並列処理はparallelを使うと実現できますが参考にしてるサイトでは
「タスク並列/非同期データフロー（TPL Dataflowライブラリ）並列処理を行うもう1つの方法としては　異なる処理（タスク）を独立して動かして、その間で非同期にデータのやり取りする方法があります。」とあり、さらに「Task クラスや Parallel クラスの総称」ですとあるのですがこれは中身の話をしているのかどうかが知りたいです。

「TPL Dataflow」ライブラリを検索してみましたがコーディングの解説がなく実装原理？のことしかでてないのですがどう理解すればいいのでしょうか？

参考サイト(最下部)：　https://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/AsyncVariation.html#dataflow

```
class Program  
{           

public static async Task<int> method()
{
    return await Task<int>.Run(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("finish");
        return 1;
    });
}


public static void method3()
{
    Console.WriteLine("finish");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    //task
    Task task = Task.Run(new Action(method3));
    //Parallel
    Parallel.Invoke(new Action(method3));

    Task<int> t = method();
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

参考サイトには、関連情報へのリンクがありますよ。
ちゃんと全文を読んで、張られているリンクの先を読むべです。

[NuGet ギャラリーの TPL Dataflow ページ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/)

[Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow 4.5.24 

Microsoft TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/)

[Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

プログラムのドキュメントに飛ばし読みは禁物です。
じっくり読みましょう。